# send gmail emails with jwt-google api auth

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am trying to send email using nodejs and google api auth and jwt.
i get the following  error:

```
      code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Precondition check failed.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'failedPrecondition'
    }
```

and this is my code:

```
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  googleKey.client_email,
  null,
  googleKey.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'],
  'email@xxx-cloud.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
)

function sendMessage(auth, from, to, subject, content) {
  // The Gmail API requires url safe Base64
  // (replace '+' with '-', and '/' with '_')
  var encodedEmail = new Buffer(
    'From: ' + from + '\r\n' + 'To: ' + to + '\r\n' + 'Subject: ' + subject + '\r\n\r\n' + content,
  )
    .toString('base64')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')

  var gmail = google.gmail('v1')
  var request = gmail.users.messages.send(
    {
      auth: auth,
      userId: 'email@xxx-cloud.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      resource: {
        raw: encodedEmail,
      },
    },
  )
}
```

I tried everything but i keep getting this error.

Comment: Nodemailer is much easier. Did you try it?

Comment: i have to do this with google api...

Answer (score 0):

remove `@xxx-cloud.iam.gserviceaccount.com` from your email.

i.e `email@xxx-cloud.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to `email`

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who is facing the same issue, it was async-await related issue. just needs to put everything in one async function and await for the auth.